# How to substring variable and concatenate it with url in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

I want to substring a variable which is my JPA class id field and then add it to an URL in Thymeleaf.

My URL is like

```
/Myapplication/sortddoc/value=__${entity.id}__
```

So I need to do something like

```
${entity.id}.substr(0, 8)
```

before concatenating it to the URL.

I tried to create a new Transient field in my entity class containing the substring variable but it doesn't work because it seems like to need database field that I cant provide.

Can Anyone help me, please ?

Comment: Is this your URL: `/Myapplication/sortddoc/value=`? Are you sure? Should it be something like: `/Myapplication/sortddoc?value=`? Is your `value` parameter or part of the path?

Comment: it may be both, in thymeleaf i call the external url like this  th:href="@{/Myapplication/sortddoc/value=__${entity.id}__}  but i could do it like you say, my problem is how to substring the ${entity.id} before add it as value

Comment: There is Thymeleaf [#strings](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings) helper object; so you are able to create temporary variable and use it in the path: `th:with="${trancatedId=#strings.substring(entity.id,0,8)}"`

Comment: That works well for me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this with Thymeleaf's [standard URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html), instead of concatenating string variables or using preprocessing (there is no need for either of those).

```
<a th:with="${value=#strings.substring(entity.id,0,8)}"
   th:href="@{/Myapplication/sortddoc/(value=${value})}"></a>
```

or

```
<a th:href="@{/Myapplication/sortddoc/(value=${#strings.substring(entity.id,0,8)})}"></a>
```